# Add javascript to only one theme/layout not the whole site

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Please believe me I have tried to search and I only get more and more confused.
I have in the past changed the default prototype reference to my Magento site for a particular theme/layout so that when I am in that particular theme/layout my prototype file is version 1.72 instead of ( i think 1.6) - I can see these changes in the source when I switch between them.

Now I need to add another set of js to the same theme/layout ( only) but I just can't find it anymore where I changed this for that theme.

My theme is defualt/default ( main) and my custom theme is defualt/vod
I thought I was in luck when I found head.phtml in the vod folder but this was only for layouts that I am not using, I want the layout empty... I am so confused and no money to pay people.
Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Use local.xml file (app/design/frontend/defualt/vod /layout/local.xml).

Comment: I have seen this suggestion before and the problem is there is no file called local.xml in that location

Comment: Maybe it is in page.xml? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: There is page.xml but only pages with layout 2 columns etc not empty which is what I am using... what is an IDE?

Comment: You can create default/vod/layout/local.xml and it should be picked up automatically. Just copy the code from page.xml and remove everything except default handler (assuming you need scripts on all pages), take addJs script inclusion as example and edit it as you need.